# How to select data from tags within text?

Tags: notepad++

I am working with Notepad++ and I am trying to extract text to file or just show only this data instead of the whole file data.

example:

```
datadatadatadatadatadatadata
datadatadatadatadatadatadata
<tag>datadatadatadata
datadatadatadata
datadatadatadatadatadata
<tag>
datadatadatadatadatadatadata
datadatadatadatadatadatadata
```

and what I need is:

```
<tag>datadatadatadata
datadatadatadata
datadatadatadatadatadata
<tag>
```

I understand that I can use the "find and replece" option but I don't understand how to use it

can somone help me please?
Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You can use find and replace (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) with a regex like this:

```
<tag>(.*)<tag>
```

You'll probably want to match the closing tag (`<tag>...</tag>`). In this case use:

```
<tag>(.*)</tag>
```

Here is a sample that matches the string you posted:

[image]